# imgburn eject the dvd drive before finishing veryfying the burn

Tags: imgburn

I am using imgburn to burn my dvds and it ejects my dvd tray right after burning the dvd even though i have eject tray unchecked during burning. Is there any way to prevent that and start the verification right away??

This is really annoying since im using a laptop.

Comment: Do you mean that it ejects the tray before verification begins? This behaviour is by design, from what I can tell.

Comment: is there any way to disable that behavior ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does appear to be designed this way on purpose.  I pulled this reasoning from the IMGBurn forums...

> CD/DVD recorders (and modern CD/DVD-ROM drives) have a chunk of RAM that holds blocks read from the disc. Some drives provide a way to clear this out, some don't.
>
> All drives need to have their block cache cleared out after writing completes and Before disc verification begins. If this weren't done, the files being verified could be read out of the block cache instead of from the disc itself, defeating the purpose of the verification pass. Also, some CD/DVD recorders need to have their recording buffers explicitly cleared between the "test" and "write" passes.
>
> The most reliable, 100%-guaranteed-to-work approach is to eject the disc and re-insert it. Watching your CD/DVD tray open and close can be startling at first, but in general it's harmless.

Comment: do you have any idea why this doesnt happen with nero burning tools??

Comment: nothing concrete, I can only surmise that Nero is written to clear these buffers in a more complicated way, and that the guy who wrote the IMGBurn software decided that this surefire method was easier to program in.  I mean, you gotta admit, just forcing an eject which will do all that is easier and makes for a smaller program, which is what he was shooting for.  That, and it's a free program.

Comment: true that its just so annoying with a laptop when you leave your dvds to burn and then come back and you need to verify i guess its gotta do

Comment: I agree.  It's possibly a deal breaker in your case which might force you to use different burning software, if it forces you to change your habits when using the computer.  The saving grace is that if you do have to find something else, you didn't lose any money on this one.